# métodos estáticos en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, poo, ecmascript-6

> En ES5

Partiendo de que los métodos estáticos en los lenguajes de programación se crean  sin la necesidad de que exista una instancia previa de la clase a ocupar; en ES5 se manejaría del modo siguiente

Usando el método `Object.definePorperty()` que ayuda a definir una propiedad estática sobre un objeto

**EJEMPLO**

```
let HumanBeign = () =>
{

}

Object.defineProperty(HumanBeign, 'message', {
  value: () => {
    return 'This is delicious'
  }
})

console.log(HumanBeign.message())
```

Donde:

1.- Tenemos una función principal llamada `HumanBeign()`

2.- `Object` es el constructor  y a través del método `defineProperty()` podemos declarar una nueva propiedad al objeto o declarar una propiedad nueva

Recibe tres parámetros:

1. Object => Que es la función `HumanBeign` sobre la cual trabajaremos para definir un contenido
2. propiedad => Es la propiedad identificada por un nombre que va a ser modificada, en este caso añadirle un contenido
3. Descriptor => Recibe diferentes valores, uno de ellos es `value` que será directamente asignado como el valor de la propiedad declarada, que para este ejemplo es `message` un método que simplemente retornará un valor

Para el presente ejemplo +unicamente se va a encargar de retornar un valor en forma de cadena de texto

Al final mandamos imprimir el valor del modo siguiente:

`console.log(HumanBeign.message())`

Por que nos valimos del método `defineProperty()` para agregar una propiedad y un valor por defecto a esa propiedad; de modo tal que cuando imprimimos, solo hacemos el llamado a la función y mediante el operador de `.` accedemos al recién creado método `message()`

Con lo que al final tendremos un mensaje similar a:

`this is delicious`

**¿Cómo puedo declarar parámetros en el ejemplo anterior?**

Basta con que a la clave `value()` en sus paréntesis le asignes un parámetro en forma de variable del modo siguiente y luego en la invocación del método declararle un valor

```
let HumanBeign = () =>
{

}

Object.defineProperty(HumanBeign, 'message', {
  value: (name) => {
    return name
  }
})

console.log(HumanBeign.message("Alfa"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> EN ES6

Tenemos un *sugar sintax* que nos acerca mas a la estructura genérica de la declaración de métodos estáticos que se manejan en otros lenguajes

Partiendo del siguiente ejemplo:

```
class HumanBeign
{
  static eating()
  {
    return 'eating delicious'
  }
}

console.log(HumanBeign.eating())
```

Podemos observar lo siguiente:

1. La clase Principal llamada `HumanBeign{}` engloba a un método estático llamado `eating()` que simplemente retorna un valor en forma de cadena de texto así `eating is delicious`
2. Al final para poder imprimir el valor, como no requerimos una instanciación de la clase, si no de la clase en si misma solo con el operador de `.` accedemos de este modo `ClaseNombre.metodoNombre()`

Sin embargo si haces lo siguiente verás como internamente el navegador no deja de tratar a la clase como una `function`

```
typeof(HumanBeign)
"function"
```

Que termina siendo muy similar a lo que realizamos en el primer ejemplo con la sintaxis de ES5